# Opening pdf files with the Trigger.io in-app browser?

Tags: pdf, trigger.io

I have a hybrid mobile app built on Trigger.io that opens links (some of them are user generated content) in the [in-app child browser](http://docs.trigger.io/en/latest/modules/tabs.html) (`forge.tabs` module) per default. When trying to open a .pdf document the screen will stay blank white (tested on both Android and iOS).

Here is a cut down version of the code I'm using:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
  window.forge.tabs.open( $(this).attr('href') );
  return false;
});
```

I would expect to either view the document in the in-app browser or be able to download it to the device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your PDFs are local, you'll need to do a "getURL" first.

Here's a function that works just fine for me:

```
function showPDF (pdfName) {
    forge.tools.getURL(pdfName, function (myPDF ) { forge.tabs.open(myPDF); });
}
```

Then just call showPDF with a relative or absolute url i.e.

```
<button class="btn" type="button" onclick="showPDF('assets/pdf/sample.pdf');">
```

Comment: This seems to work in **iOS** (just views the document without any download option, which is the default for Mobile Safari). However, on **Android** I cannot get the pdf to load. Maybe this is because Android would usually attempt to download the file by default.

Comment: Android unfortunately has no built in PDF viewer and I don't think the tabs browser in Forge will attempt to download files it can't display.